# JavaScript - Instantiate from require

Tags: javascript

I have a Node program. This program is importing some code. That code looks like the following:

**sample.js**

```
function SampleModel() {
  this.name = 'Test';
}
module.exports = SampleModel;
```

I am using `SampleModel` in another file. Currently, I am successfully using it like this:

**another.js**

```
var SampleModel = require('./sampleModel');
var model = new SampleModel();
```

For the purpose of education, is there a way to condense these two lines down to a single line of JavaScript? If so, how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
var model = new (require('./sampleModel'))();
```

It's quite common to access the `require`d module directly in the import line, but you'll mostly see property access (like `require('events').EventEmitter`).